# Why text() is matched by XSL template in non-#default mode?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<x>
  <y>test</y>
</x>
```

This is XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:template match="/x">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="//y" mode="foo"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#default">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I expect this output, because the second template should be reached for the `<y/>` element:

```
<x/>
```

However, I'm getting:

```
<x>test</x>
```

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not have a template matching `y` in mode `foo`. Therefore it is processed by the [built-in template rule](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) of:

```
<xsl:apply-templates mode="#current">
```

and its child text node by:

```
<xsl:value-of select="string(.)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [built-in templates](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#built-in-rule) that in XSLT 1 and 2 recursively process child nodes and copy text through. In XSLT 3 it can depend on your `xsl:mode on-no-match` declaration what happens.